# Como utilizar dll em Java

Tags: java, eclipse, dll

Como faço para incluir arquivos `dll` em um projeto em Java utilizando o Eclipse?

Comment: Deseja incluir e utilizar métodos dela?

Comment: Isto mesmo ricardo. Estou tentando acessar a porta serial através da biblioteca jSSC, e esta biblioteca possui o arquivo jSSC-2.8_x86_64.dll no qual devo adicionar ao projeto. Quando adicionar, como posso incluir e utilizar os métodos dela?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você deve usar umas das **APIs JAVA** disponíveis para acessar [código nativo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_nativo), são essas:
[JNI (Java Native Interface)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) e [JNA (Java Native Access)](https://github.com/twall/jna). 

JNI é a API oficial do Java (Oracle) e JNA é open source mantido pela comunidade. 
Enquanto ambos tem o mesmo objetivo, o desenvolvimento do JNA foi focado em simplificar ao máximo a implementação, problema comum na implementação usando JNI. 
Eu recomendo a utilização de JNA para você atingir seu objetivo, segue um exemplo que você pode usar como referencia a sua implementação:

**Exemplo de aplicação nativa em C++ originador da DLL**

```
#include "simpleDLL.h"

#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace simpleDLLNS
{
    char simpleDLL::giveVoidPtrGetChar(void* param)
    {
        if(param != 0)
        {
        char* paramChrPtr = (char*)param;
        return *paramChrPtr;
        }
        else
        {
            return 'x';
        }

    }

    int simpleDLL::giveIntGetInt(int a)
    {
        return 2*a;
    }

    void simpleDLL::simpleCall(void)
    {
        int x = 3;
        return;
    }

    int simpleDLL::giveVoidPtrGetInt(void* param)
    {
        if(param!=0)
        {
            int* x = (int*)param;
            return *x;

        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

}
```

**Chamada JNA a métodos da DLL acima:**

```
package jnahelloworldtest;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLong;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.*;

/** Simple example of native library declaration and usage. */
public class Main {
    public interface simpleDLL extends Library {
        simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary(
            (Platform.isWindows() ? "simpleDLL" : "simpleDLLLinuxPort"), simpleDLL.class);
        // it's possible to check the platform on which program runs, for example purposes we assume that there's a linux port of the library (it's not attached to the downloadable project)
        byte giveVoidPtrGetChar(Pointer param); // char giveVoidPtrGetChar(void* param);
        int giveVoidPtrGetInt(Pointer param);   //int giveVoidPtrGetInt(void* param);
        int giveIntGetInt(int a);               // int giveIntGetInt(int a);
        void simpleCall();                      // void simpleCall();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        simpleDLL sdll = simpleDLL.INSTANCE;

        sdll.simpleCall();  // call of void function

        int a = 3;
        int result1 = sdll.giveIntGetInt(a);  // calling function with int parameter&result
        System.out.println("giveIntGetInt("+a+"): " + result1);

        String testStr = "ToBeOrNotToBe";
        Memory mTest = new Memory(testStr.length()+1);  // '+1' remember about extra byte for \0 character!
        mTest.setString(0, testStr);
        String testReturn = mTest.getString(0); // you can see that String got properly stored in Memory object
        System.out.println("String in Memory:"+testReturn);

        Memory intMem = new Memory(4);  // allocating space
        intMem.setInt(0, 666); // setting allocated memory to an integer
        Pointer intPointer = intMem.getPointer(0);

        int int1 = sdll.giveVoidPtrGetInt(Pointer.NULL); // passing null, getting default result
        System.out.println("giveVoidPtrGetInt(null):" + int1); // passing int stored in Memory object, getting it back
        int int2 = sdll.giveVoidPtrGetInt(intMem);
       //int int2 = sdll.giveVoidPtrGetInt(intPointer);  causes JVM crash, use memory object directly!
        System.out.println("giveVoidPtrGetInt(666):" + int2);

        byte char1 = sdll.giveVoidPtrGetChar(Pointer.NULL);  // passing null, getting default result
        byte char2 = sdll.giveVoidPtrGetChar(mTest);        // passing string stored in Memory object, getting first letter

        System.out.println("giveVoidPtrGetChar(null):" + (char)char1);
        System.out.println("giveVoidPtrGetChar('ToBeOrNotToBe'):" + (char)char2);

    }
}
```

**Tabela de Mapeamento**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mais referencias:** 

[Getting Started with JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md)
[Fonte do exemplo](http://blog.mwrobel.eu/how-to-call-dll-methods-from-java/)